# Is RSS feed submission a search engine ranking factor now?

Tags: seo, search-engines, rss

Is RSS submission worth doing now? Is it still considered as SEO ranking factor?

Comment: Neither RSS submission nor any kind of sitemap have any value in terms of ranking, they are used to index content not for ranking.

Comment: I don't think RSS feeds have ever been a ranking factor. Do you remember where you heard this?

Answer (score 2):

RSS feeds and even sitemaps don't contribute to ranking at all. They are used by search engines to identify links to crawl and it is the pages at those links once crawled combined with valuable back links from reputable sites which contribute to your page ranking.